# Best way to parse suffixed words

Tags: python, parsing, context-free-grammar, tagging

I need a parser that recognizes the part of speech according to the last letter of each word. I've used Python but I'm not sure the available CFG parsers will accept this.

Let's take Esperanto words for example. All adjectives end with -a (eg. 'granda' for big), and all nouns end with -o (eg. 'hundo' for dog). So here's a toy grammar:

S -> A N | A S N

A -> (any word ending with -a)

N -> (any word ending with -o)

The sentence: "granda bela animalo hundo" (sic!) should parse as follows:

(S (A granda) (S (A bela) (N animalo)) (N hundo))

Does anyone have an idea how to code this? I'm trying to make the grammar as simple as possible. Sorry if this looks weird - it's complicated...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method

```
word = "granda"

if word.endswith('o'):
    print "Noun"
elif word.endswith('a'):
    print "Adjective"
```

Comment: Thanks ILMS! The str.endswith is good, but the CFG format only accepts production rules in the type of Noun -> hundo. I haven't figured out how to insert commands. Maybe I'll have to make a parser from scratch, but that feels funny because the issue seems really basic.